# python-docx как выбрать определённый кусок текста из файла docx и сохранить его в новом документе?

Tags: python, python-docx

Как в python-docx выбрать определённый кусок текста из файла docx и сохранить его в новом документе docx? Куски текста должны выбираться по заголовку например "Подавал". Выбранный текст должен быть до следующего заголовка "Кровля"[пример того, какой текст надо выбрать в скрине]. Если python-docx это не сделать, то посоветуйте другую библиотеку, формат исходных файлов не принципиален docx или txt или pdf без разницы.

Comment: https://yandex.kz/search/?text=python-docx+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA+%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0+%D0%B8%D0%B7+%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0+docx+%D0%B8+%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE+%D0%B2+%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%3F&rdrnd=639627&lr=10298&redircnt=1685980921.1

Answer (score 0):

Так как нет информации о том, какую информацию точно надо искать, и насколько вариативны ваши доки, могу предложить 2 варианта, которые приходят в голову:

- Вариант "И так сойдет":

используете [`docx2txt`](https://github.com/ankushshah89/python-docx2txt), делаете просто дамп текста, и в этом дампе ищете нужные вам заголовки (последствия: не известно, где в тексте еще встречаются нужные вам слова).

- Вариант с [`python-docx`](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Тут вам нужно понимать, что обычный текст в ooxml-доках состоит из абзацев (`paragraph`), которые состоят из "последовательностей" (`run`). Помимо абзацев, в доках могут быть таблицы, формы, и дофига еще чего.

Мы идем по документу, ищем интересующее нас начало, и ждем интересующий нас конец:

```
from docx import Document

collected_text = []
start_text = 'Наше начало'
end_text = 'Наш конец'

doc = Document('demo.docx')
collect = False
for par in doc.paragraphs:
    # обратите внимание: paragraph.text сливает несколько run-ов в один
    # если вы хотите больше контроля, идите глубже по paragraph.runs
    current_text = par.text 
    if current_text.startswith(start_text): # если заголовок хотите полностью - используйте обычный ==
        collect = True
    elif current_text.startswith(end_text):
        break
    if collect:
        collected_text.append(current_text)
```

Это минимальная версия, когда у нас в документе есть только текст и мы уверены, что повторений заголовков не будет больше нигде в документе. Эти и другие подводные камни надо как-то обходить, я дал начальный пример по вашему запросу.